# Is CloudFlare's free SSL actually secure?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I've just set up CloudFlare on my web app. The free version, since my app isn't generating any revenue right now.

Now all my traffic is routing through CloudFlare's servers, correct? And that connection is "secure" because it's under HTTPS -- Chrome even displays the green padlock.

But CloudFlare is still communicating with *my* server over HTTP (unsecure connection), are they not?

Doesn't that mean all my client's data is sent in the clear between CloudFlare and my server? And that makes it not really secure at all, despite what Chrome thinks?

Comment: @EricJ. No. I'm not too concerned if CloudFlare pulls my static content securely or not -- there's no sensitive data in there. When I signed up it came with dozens of features -- I guess I'm talking about the "Crypto" service. Specifically, the "SSL (with SPDY)" setting. I've got mine set to "Flexible" since I don't have a cert on my server. I guess I should have read the help text; it confirms my suspicions: "There is an encrypted connection between your website visitors and CloudFlare, but **not** from CloudFlare to your server."

Comment: Note that servers are normally connected to each other by a relatively secure connection. It would be tricky for attackers to get access (excepting intelligence agencies and ISP's). Client connections may be set up over an untrusted WiFi connection in a coffee shop.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's a good point. I guess it would be very difficult to pull off a targeted attack.

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

The "Flexible" option of the "Crypto / SSL (with SPDY)" setting is *not* secure. If you read the "Help" text it says:

> There is an encrypted connection between your website visitors and CloudFlare, but **not from CloudFlare to your server**.

You must install an SSL certificate on your own server and then select the "Full SSL (strict)" option to be secure.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the origin for the CDN (i.e. your servers that provide the original version of the content to be distributed across the CDN) to provide data using HTTPS.  With the pro version (which you are not currently using) you can also use the SPDY protocol.  HTTPS communication between the CDN and your servers protects that part of the communication path.

Additionally, and optionally, you can use [Authenticated Origin Pulls](https://blog.cloudflare.com/protecting-the-origin-with-tls-authenticated-origin-pulls/) (also available in the free version) to ensure that the CDN and origin (you) are both who you claim to be.

Comment: I have written a guide on how to setup this on Apache. Hope that others find useful. https://www.leowkahman.com/2016/03/10/apache-cloudflare-authenticated-origin-pulls-configuration/